# How can I split a zfs pool for storing VMs and Glusterfs separately on Proxmox?

Tags: zfs, proxmox, glusterfs

I have a ProxmoxVE server which I created the following zpool on:

```
root@thor:\~# zpool list

NAME     SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT

Asgard  5.45T   816K  5.45T        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE

root@thor:~# zfs list
NAME     USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
Asgard   543K  3.52T      128K  /Asgard  -
```

And it has the following disks:

```
root@thor:~# lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0   1.8T  0 part 
└─sda9               8:9    0     8M  0 part 
sdb                  8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1               8:17   0  1007K  0 part 
├─sdb2               8:18   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb3               8:19   0 465.3G  0 part 
  ├─pve-swap       253:0    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root       253:1    0    96G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta 253:2    0   3.5G  0 lvm  
  │ └─pve-data     253:4    0 338.4G  0 lvm  
  └─pve-data_tdata 253:3    0 338.4G  0 lvm  
    └─pve-data     253:4    0 338.4G  0 lvm  
sdc                  8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdc1               8:33   0   1.8T  0 part 
└─sdc9               8:41   0     8M  0 part 
sdd                  8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdd1               8:49   0   1.8T  0 part 
└─sdd9               8:57   0     8M  0 par
```

sdb is Proxmox and the rest are in a raidz zpool named `Asgard`. I want to use 1TB of this zpool as storage for 2 VMs. Remaining 2.52TB I want to dedicate to GlusterFS (which will then be linked to k8s nodes running on the VMs through a storage class). What's the right way to do this in Proxmox (maybe zfs subvolumes)?

Please don't tell me to use Ceph. I've used Ceph. It's great, but it requires more resources than I have for this build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use xfs instead of ZFS for Glusterfs volumes following [these docs](https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Quick-Start-Guide/Quickstart/#installing-glusterfs-a-quick-start-guide) and partition off 1TB ext4 for VM images from one of the 1.8 TB drives. No zfs required :D